# My variables in my data frame are numbers which are counted as characters

Tags: r

In R, I have a variable column of numbers which are being counted as variables. When I do as.numeric() on it I get the "NA caused by coercion" and nothing works.

This is what the code looks like
[image]

Volume.x has no NA in it, every single value is a number but it's read as a character and doing the as.numeric() prints a bunch of NA's

Comment: It may have some elements that are not numeric.  The `NA`s are the result of applying the `as.numeric` on non-numeric elements.  Without a small reproducible example with `dput`, it is difficult to say what your data have

Comment: @akrun in the dataset i went through every value and for the ones im trying to convert to numeric, it's all numbers like there's no NA and no characters

Comment: Do you have any `,`. I would consider showing `dput` of some part of your datat that gives the issues

Comment: @akrun want to get married? You're right it was because of the comma

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the `,` and convert to `numeric`

```
df1$Volume.x <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df1$Volume.x))
```